# Pivot_longer but keep rownames

Tags: r, tidyr

I am trying to apply the function pivot_longer but it's deleting my rownames, wich I want to keep. Can someone help me with this little issue please ?

Here is the original table :

```
                   Somme_Ill  Moyenne_Ill Somme_R_454 Moyenne_R_454
Altiarchaeota               0 0.000000e+00           0     0.0000000
Asgardaeota                 0 0.000000e+00           0     0.0000000
Crenarchaeota               2 6.666667e-02           8     0.2666667
Diapherotrites             21 7.000000e-01           9     0.3000000
Euryarchaeota              55 1.833333e+00          59     1.9666667
Hadesarchaeaeota            0 0.000000e+00           0     0.0000000
Hydrothermarchaeota         0 0.000000e+00           0     0.0000000
Korarchaeota                0 0.000000e+00           0     0.0000000
Nanoarchaeaeota            22 7.333333e-01          18     0.6000000
Thaumarchaeota          33623 1.120767e+03       27157   905.2333333
```

And the outcome after pivot_longer :

```
Moyenne_Ill Moyenne_R_454 Tech        Somme
         <dbl>         <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>
 1      0              0     Somme_Ill       0
 2      0              0     Somme_R_454     0
 3      0              0     Somme_Ill       0
 4      0              0     Somme_R_454     0
 5      0.0667         0.267 Somme_Ill       2
 6      0.0667         0.267 Somme_R_454     8
 7      0.7            0.3   Somme_Ill      21
 8      0.7            0.3   Somme_R_454     9
 9      1.83           1.97  Somme_Ill      55
10      1.83           1.97  Somme_R_454    59
11      0              0     Somme_Ill       0
12      0              0     Somme_R_454     0
13      0              0     Somme_Ill       0
14      0              0     Somme_R_454     0
15      0              0     Somme_Ill       0
16      0              0     Somme_R_454     0
17      0.733          0.6   Somme_Ill      22
18      0.733          0.6   Somme_R_454    18
19   1121.           905.    Somme_Ill   33623
20   1121.           905.    Somme_R_454 27157
```

I just applied this command :

`Arc<-Arc%>% pivot_longer(cols = c("Somme_Ill","Somme_R_454"), names_to = "Tech", values_to ="Somme")`

Comment: tidyverse functions do not preserve rownames. You can use `tibble::rownames_to_column()` to turn your rownames into a proper column.

Comment: ... or `Arc <- as_tibble(Arc, rownames="RowName") %>% pivot_longer(...)`, where you can edit `"RowName"` to use the column name of your choice.  Row names are not stored in a column in a data frame, which is why tidyverse functions, as a rule, do not preserve them.